# Copy to various columns based on cell contents

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and I need to create macro, which will find all cells in column A that contain "test", "data" or "new" and copy all these cells to column B, starting in B2, all other cells should be copied to column C, starting in C2.

Comment: Hi, I'm new so I just try to record macro, but without any results

Comment: You could have also tried `vlookup` in Excel formula level :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your VBA editor and paste below code in Sheet1 (under Microsoft Excel Object):

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyMacro()
Dim iLastRow As Long 
Dim i As Long 
Dim sVal As String

iLastRow = range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row 'get last row in use

For i = 2 To iLastRow 'iterate trough rows from second to last in use
    sVal = range("A" & i).Value
    If sVal = "test" Or sVal = "data" Or sVal = "new" Then
        range("B" & i).Value = sVal
    Else
        If sVal <> "" Then range("C" & i).Value = sVal
    End If

Next i 
End Sub
```

Ensure that mouse pointer is set somewhere inside procedure `MyMacro` and hit F5 to execute code. It should do the magic you've asked for :-)

Comment: Thx for the code!!! It works grat! Could you just advise how to change it if I have in column not only word "data" but "datacash"/"datapast" and it should as well be copy to column B?

Comment: Just replace the line `If sVal = "test" Or sVal = "data" Or sVal = "new" Then` with `If InStr(1, sVal, "test") > 0 Or InStr(1, sVal, "data") > 0 Or InStr(1, sVal, "new") > 0 Then` ...

Answer (score 1):

Understand you have accepted an answer, but if you are going to do lots of these type of filtering, then iterating through cells can be negative for performance. **Try an `array`**. Also use **`LIKE`** operator to compare the values, which is the perfect `wildcard operator`. Add the following code into a VBA project module. Add a button in the sheet and call the subroutine via `button click event`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub filterSpecifics()
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim vArray As Variant
Dim i As Integer

    lastRow = Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Sheets(3).Range("A1").Resize(lastRow)
    vArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng.Value)

    For i = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
        If Not IsEmpty(vArray(i)) Then
            If Not vArray(i) Like "test*" And _ 
                 Not vArray(i) Like "data*" And Not vArray(i) Like "new*" Then
                vArray(i) = ""  '-- remove the value
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    '-- output the array to the column B
    rng.Offset(0, 1).Resize(UBound(vArray)) = Application.Transpose(vArray)
End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I am okay with arrays... However, for someone new in coding this might be confusing. I believe my code is easier to read for a beginner.. It should help a user to easier understand Excel OM ... Thanks for suggestion. :-)

Comment: Well I meant to send the comment to the user ;-)  intact either user iterate through range or array it is the same logic. I see in VBA space lots of users are requesting codes without programming knowledge. Sigh... But hey it is good to have more choices. And you know the value of the code I write ;-)