# Excel multiple string search

Tags: excel, vba

I have Sheet2 with data (names of products) alphabetically sorted by column yielding 26 columns plus one column for numeric data. On Sheet1 there is a list of nearly 10,000 names of products which is to be tested whether we have them on Sheet2 or not. To search one name at a time is a matter of craze, so I was thinking if we could bulk search data in Sheet1 and next to each cell the search result will be shown with the address of the cell where that product is found in Sheet2, or not found, such as:

```
SEARCH STRINGS    SEARCH RESULT

Vodafone          A4
Mirinda           C105
Coca-Cola         Y59
HeroHonda         not found
Bournvita         S27
Maggi             not found
```

I have done some search to find similar code for what is needed above, and found the following code at: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/714965-search.html, which does the search for one string. Can this script be modified to yeild the desired results?

```
Sub DataSearch()
Dim Data() As Variant
Dim DstWks As Worksheet
Dim Food As String
Dim N As Variant
Dim R As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim RngEnd As Range
Dim SrcWks As Worksheet

Set SrcWks = Worksheets("Test 2")
Set DstWks = Worksheets("Test1")

R = 6
Food = DstWks.Range("E3")
N = DstWks.Range("E4")

  If DstWks.Range("C6") <> "" Then
     DstWks.Range("C6").CurrentRegion.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
  End If

  Set Rng = SrcWks.Range("A4:E4")
  Set RngEnd = SrcWks.Cells(Rows.Count, Rng.Column).End(xlUp)
  Set Rng = IIf(RngEnd.Row < Rng.Row, Rng, SrcWks.Range(Rng, RngEnd))

  ReDim Data(1 To Rng.Rows.Count, 1 To Rng.Columns.Count)
  Data = Rng.Value

    For I = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
      If Data(I, 1) = N And InStr(1, Data(I, 3), Food, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
         DstWks.Cells(R, "C").Resize(1, Rng.Columns.Count) = Rng.Rows(I).Value
         R = R + 1
      End If
    Next I

End Sub
```

Always appreciating your invaluable assistance.

Comment: terry welcome to StackOverflow :) check this [post out.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578474/copy-to-various-columns-based-on-cell-contents/14584298#14584298) As mentioned, iterations of search via large data ranges can cause a huge performance drop. You may incorporate *wildcard* method and try out. I support arrays here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something quick and dirty such as a hlookup, and see if it returns a value to determine whether or not it is in the 10,000 products.

e.g. Assuming that in sheet 2, your data are in stored such that:
 - Each product record is in a column
 - Different products are in different columns
 - Product name is in row 1, starting with A1
Also assuming that in sheet 1,
 - Product names are in column A, starting with A1
 - There are no other data in the sheet

In Sheet 1, put the following formula in B2 (and subsequently copy it all the way to B10001):
`=IF(ISNA(HLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$1,1)),"not found",ADDRESS(1,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$1,0),1))`

Comment: Many thanks OC2PS for your practical solution which I believe will work if we considered that the first row is columns headers which are alphabets A-Z, and column 27 is NUM. Each column is just names of products that start with its letter, so the entire Sheet2 is just names of products. Will these details affect the formula above? Much appreciated..

Comment: I don't think that has any affect on the formula. Row and column names as defined by Excel remain the same whether or not you choose to show them in the sheet. You can still refer to cell using these values.

Comment: Is there a way to expand the search range from (A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$1,1) to (A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$AA$5000,1) in order to include all name of products in the search procedure? I tried it but didn't work, for certain it is HLOOKUP. If we couldn't expand the search range, is there any other way to do it? Much appreciated.

Comment: You can expand the range, but all product names must be in the same row.

Comment: That's what I mean. There must be another way since my Sheet2 has over 1.8 million names sorted alphabetically. I will search for a solution from my side. Meanwhile if you could kindly think of any other way to achieve desired results, that will be extremely generous of you. My best regards.

Comment: Not as quick or elegant, but you could try this: 1. In sheet 2, arrange product names by column instead of by row (because Excel has 1,048,576 rows but only 16,384 columns)...this way everything should fit into 2 columns. 2. In sheet 1, you can have something like the following in B2 (and subsequently copy it all the way to B10001): =CONCATENATE(IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$1048576,1)),"",ADDRESS(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$1048576,0),1,1)),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$1048576,1)),"",ADDRESS(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$1048576,0),2,1)))